# Unicode Decode Error in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, utf-8

```
TDB = csv.reader(codecs.open('data/TDS.csv', 'rb', encoding='utf-8'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

ts = db.testCol

for row in TDB:
    print row[1]
    T = {"t":row[1],
             "s": row[0]}
    post_id = ts.insert(T)
```

I not sure why i can't encode it into utf-8 while i want to insert data into database i must make it in utf8 format.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 36: invalid continuation byte
```

Before i put the encoding function, i got this from pymongo.

```
bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8
```

and i guess, this is the data it couldn't encode

```
'compleja e intelectualmente retadora , el ladrÛn de orquÌdeas es uno de esos filmes que vale la pena ver precisamente por su originalidad . '
```

Anyone know how should i do? Thanks

Comment: you're trying to read in (decode) the data as UTF8, not encode.  Make sure your file, "TDS.csv" is encoded as UTF8.

Comment: @monkut, may i know what should i do? if i want to make them output as utf8 and save to pymongo. Thanks

Comment: you first need to know what encoding the data, "TDS.csv" is.  Also, it should be noted that the csv module doesn't support unicode (which is what codecs.open() will return).

Comment: if your file is already in UTF8, you should be able to use the standard `open()` (not codecs.open()), and not worry about the conversion.

Comment: @monkut dear, it's not utf8 while its tweets extracted via live stream and I not sure it's encoding. Without calling the codec, it will raise an error to me from pymongo about they only accepting utf8 input. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this might help..

There are a list of encodings here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

`latin-1` is a common encoding used for languages in europe.

The basic flow with dealing with encodings is:

1. read in encoded content
2. content.decode("source encoding") to unicode
3. encode from unicode to desired encoding, unicode_content.encode("desired encoding")

You can try going through encodings that seem right and see which ones don't cause an error:

```
enc = "latin-1"
f = open("TSD.csv", "r")
content = f.read() # raw encoded content
u_content = content.decode(enc) # decodes from enc to unicode
utf8_content = u_content.encode("utf8")
```

Comment: Thanks. Yesterday i tried this helped too. 
row[1].decode('latin-1').encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace')